# Uso de fread en C Violación de Segmento

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu, archivo

Tengo problemas al crear dos archivos, uno en el que se escriban números random en y otro en el que se lean, el problema radica en que si se guardan los datos, pero a la hora de leer solo se lee el primer dato que es el numero de datos total y después en vez de leer los números random me marca:
*Violación de segmento (`core' generado)*

Código del programa que escribe: 
    // Escritura de n reales(1 a la vez)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int i, n= atoi(argv[1]); 
float num;
FILE *fp;
srand48(time(NULL)); 

if((fp=fopen(argv[2], "wb")) == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file.");
    exit(1);    
}   

if(fwrite(&n, sizeof(int), sizeof(n), fp) != sizeof(n)){
    fprintf(stderr,"Error writing to file");
    exit(1);
}

for(i=0; i<n; i++){
    num = drand48() * (-80.0) + 30; 
    if(fwrite(&num, sizeof(int), sizeof(num), fp) != sizeof(num)){
        fprintf(stderr,"Error writing to file");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("%f\n", num);
}

fclose(fp);
}
```

Los números que se suben al archivo on negativos o positivos y con decimales.
Este es el archivo que debería leer y el cual me marca problemas:
// Lectura de n reales(1 a la vez)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int i, n; 
float num;
FILE *fp;

if((fp=fopen(argv[2], "rb")) == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file");
    exit(1);
}

if(fread(&n, sizeof(int), sizeof(n), fp) != sizeof(n)){
    fprintf(stderr, "Error reading file");
    exit(1);
}

for(i=0; i<n; i++){
    if(fread(&num, sizeof(int), sizeof(num), fp) != sizeof(num)){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error reading file");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("%f\n",num);
}

fclose(fp);

}
```

Comment: Si hago uso de arrays en vez de ir uno por uno el código funciona bien; pero debo de hacerlo uno por uno.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Voy a centrarme en la lectura, pero estás cometiendo **exactamente el mismo error** en la escritura.

De la [página de manual de `fread`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fread.3.html):

> **SINOPSIS**
>       `size_t fread( void *ptr, size_t tam, size_t nmiemb, FILE *flujo );`
>   
>   
>   **DESCRIPCIÓN**
>       La función `fread` lee `nmiemb` elementos de datos, cada uno de `tam` bytes de largo, del flujo de datos apuntado por `flujo`, almacenándolos en el sitio apuntado por `ptr`.

Sin embargo, tu haces:

```
int i, n; 
float num;
...
fread( &n, sizeof( int ), sizeof( n ), fp ) // #1
...
fread( &num, sizeof( int ), sizeof( num ), fp ) // #2
```

En **ambos** casos estás cometiendo el mismo error: estás pasando mal tanto el 2º como el 3<sup>er</sup> argumento.

El resultado de `tam * nmiemb` ha de ser **el total de bytes a leer**. Sin embargo, suponiendo un sistema con `sizeof( int ) == 4` y `sizeof( float ) == 4`, el resultado es:

> 4 * 4 == 16

Es decir, estás intentando leer mas *bytes* de aquellos para los que realmente tienes espacio disponible.

Simplemente, llama a `fread( )` con los argumentos correctos:

```
if( fread( &n, sizeof( n ), 1, fp ) != sizeof( n ) ) // #1
...
if( fread( &num, sizeof( num ), 1, fp ) != sizeof( num ) ) // #2
```

Como observación, tu código **es dependiente de la arquitectura**, así que asegurate de generar el archivo y leerlo después **en la misma máquina**. No te recomiendo que intentes generarlo en una y leerlo en otra.

Comment: El error era la comparación fread( &n, sizeof( n ), 1, fp ) con sizeof( n ); la comparación debía ser con 1; ya que voy leyendo de uno en uno.